# Custom color map google GeoChart Google Developers

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

I need the color of the clicked region to change color. Thank you!

I tried to use the documentation settings but I did not succeed ..

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#configuration-options

[image]

```js
var options = {
  region: 'BR',
  resolution: 'provinces',
  datalessRegionColor: 'white',
  defaultColor: '#ebebeb',
  enableRegionInteractivity: true,
  displayMode: 'regions',
  height: 480,
};
```

Comment: Can you provide some more information and your current code to see where exactly you are struggling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the only way to do this is to create dynamic content on your map.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-dynamic

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#configuration-options